# JQuery: Putting a new funtion into my code stops all other functions

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with a temperature-based timer I'm building. I have a start function and functions to raise and lower the desired temperature, and then a countdown by seconds. The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var desiredTemp = 10;
var actualTemp = 12;
var tempMatch = false;
var degreeTime = 5;
var seconds = degreeTime;


$("#actualBox").text(timer(seconds));
/*This returns the outcome of the tick and counter        functions.*/
function timer(seconds) {
    return actualTemp;
}
/*This checks whether the temp should drop by one or not.*/
function tick() {
    if(seconds === 0) {
        actualTemp -= 1;
        seconds = degreeTime;
    }
    else {
        seconds -= 1;
        $("#actualBox").text(timer(seconds));
    }
}
/*this sets the count interval to run the tick     function every second*/
function counter() {
    count = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}


/*functions to raise and lower desired temp*/
function changeTemp(degree) {
    desiredTemp += degree;
}

function showDesired() {
    return desiredTemp;
}


/*when you click Start, this runs the counter*/
$("#start").click(function(){
    counter();
});

$('#lowerTemp').click(function(){
    changeTemp(-1);
    $('#desiredBox').text(showDesired());
});

$('#raiseTemp').click(function(){
    changeTemp(1);
    $('#desiredBox').text(showDesired());
});

});
```

Now when i insert this code anywhere:

```
function doneCheck() {
    if actualTemp === desiredTemp;
    jQuery('#actualBox').css({"background-color:    green"});
}
```

The timer and change temp functions completely stop working. I have searched and not found any relevant information as to why. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `if actualTemp === desiredTemp;` syntax error. Change to `if (actualTemp == desiredTemp)`

Comment: In addition to the above, learn to use the console to debug JS logic. Press F12 to open it in your browser. You will see errors and warnings displayed there.

Answer (score 1):

Fix syntax errors

```
function doneCheck() {
    if(actualTemp == desiredTemp)
       $('#actualBox').css({"background-color: green;"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntactical mistakes correct those and call doneCheck() function where do you want.

```js
var desiredTemp = 10;
var actualTemp = 12;
var tempMatch = false;
var degreeTime = 5;
var seconds = degreeTime;

$(document).ready(function(){


$("#actualBox").text(timer(seconds));
/*This returns the outcome of the tick and counter        functions.*/
function timer(seconds) {
    return actualTemp;
}
/*This checks whether the temp should drop by one or not.*/
function tick() {
    if(seconds === 0) {
        actualTemp -= 1;
        seconds = degreeTime;
    }
    else {
        seconds -= 1;
        $("#actualBox").text(timer(seconds));
    }
}
/*this sets the count interval to run the tick     function every second*/
function counter() {
    count = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}


/*functions to raise and lower desired temp*/
function changeTemp(degree) {
    desiredTemp += degree;
}

function showDesired() {
    return desiredTemp;
}


/*when you click Start, this runs the counter*/
$("#start").click(function(){
    counter();
});

$('#lowerTemp').click(function(){
    changeTemp(-1);
    $('#desiredBox').text(showDesired());
});

$('#raiseTemp').click(function(){
    changeTemp(1);
    $('#desiredBox').text(showDesired());
});

});


function doneCheck() {
  if(actualTemp === desiredTemp)
    jQuery('#actualBox').css("background-color","green");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="lowerTemp">lowerTemp</button>
<button id="raiseTemp">raiseTemp</button>
<button id="desiredBox">desiredBox</button>
<button id="actualBox">actualBox</button>
```